# How can I get ByteBuffer body from WMQTextMessage.java instead of calling getText()?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq

I have a Spring Boot application which is listening to IBM MQ using the JMS API. The application is running in a severely memory constrained environment.

I receive a `TextMessage` object. I can call `getText()` and get the message content in `String` form, but this `String` is actually being created from a `ByteBuffer` which already exists in `WMQTextMessage.java`. Therefore, I don't want to call `getText()` since creating a new `String` from the `ByteBuffer` will use more memory.

Instead I want to get the `ByteBuffer` directly from the `WMQTextMessage.java`. There is a method called `public byte[] _exportBody` in `WMQTextMessage.java`, but I can't call this method I think.

Can someone please help me with this? Here is the simple code I have:

```
@JmsListener()
public void messageListener (TextMessage message) {
   String data = message.getText(); //need to avoid this and get data in byte[] to save space
}
```

Comment: If possible, you may want to ask the sender application to send BytesMessage instead of TextMessage. You could then use methods to read data in the way you want.

Comment: Hii. Actually I have no control of the sender . I can only receive as TextMessage

Comment: Why do you think using a `byte[]` as opposed to a `String` will save you memory? It will use about the same amount of memory. Also why wouldn't you be able to call that method? Just cast it to the message type you want.

Comment: Hi. Actually I just updated the question again. A ByteBuffer body object already exists. Calling .getText() creates a new object which ofcourse will use more memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `_export()` is a `public` method on `WMQTextMessage` then you should be able to cast the `TextMessage` to `WMQTextMessage` and call it no problem, e.g.:

```
@JmsListener()
public void messageListener (TextMessage message) {
   byte[] data = ((WMQTextMessage)message)._export();
}
```

However, since the `_export()` method returns a `byte[]` and *not* a `ByteBuffer` then it is almost certainly **copying** the data from the `ByteBuffer` into a new `byte[]` and therefore would use extra heap just like calling `getText()`.

IBM MQ is closed source as far as I can tell. If you're decompiling the client jar in order to actually look at `WMQTextMessage.java` then you may be violating your software license agreement with IBM or possibly even the [DMCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act). It may sound silly for something so innocuous, but the laws around technology are often silly given that the folks who write them don't usually understand the nuances of the technology in the first place. I recommend you work directly with IBM to get these specific questions answered.

Comment: Hi thanks for this. Any idea what the 2 arguments are for ```_exportBody()```

Comment: I don't have access to the source so I can't say.